# tuple as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic

I am a little confused if it possible an how to use a variadic tuple as an argument in  a function and how to initialize it.

```
    template <typename T, Arg ...> 
      void foo (int a, std::tuple<T, sizeof(Arg)> TupleTest);
...

foo(TupleTest(2, "TEST", 5.5));
```

How could that be implemented using c++0x?

Comment: This is a bit unclear - what are you trying to achieve? You can just say `template <typename ...Args> void foo(std::tuple<Args...> t) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: What is TupleTest? Is it a type of tuple? Why `int a` is outside of the Tuple? What's the meaning of putting `sizeof(Arg)` there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to get the number of template arguments. Just do this:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(int a, std::tuple<T...> TupleTest);

// make_tuple so we don't need to enter all the type names
foo(0, std::make_tuple(2, "TEST", 5.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want `sizeof` for? Just use the variadic expansion:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg ...> 
void foo(int a, std::tuple<T, Arg...> TupleTest);
```

And here, `TupleTest` is the *name of the argument*, not a type name. So when invoking the method, don’t use it.

```
foo(42, std::tuple<int, char const*, double>(2, "TEST", 5.5));
```

Finally, the type argument `T` serves no real purpose (unless you explicitly want to forbid an empty template list) so you can just remove it without loss.