# Using tuple as a parameter of a function

Tags: c++11

Hi I'm trying to pass a tuple as a parameter to a function.
I would like to not to specify the amount of elements in the tuple (I followed this example: [tuple as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747406/tuple-as-function-argument))

What is missing now is how I can count the number of element into the tuple in order to access it with std::get

```
#include<tuple>
#include<iostream>

template <typename... T> void fill(std::tuple<T...> values) {
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T...>::value << '\n';
    //std::cout << std::get<0>(values) << '\n';
    //std::cout << std::get<1>(values) << '\n';
}
int main() {
    fill(std::make_tuple(2.));
    fill(std::make_tuple(2., 5));
}
```

tuple_size seems not suitable to be used (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)

Comment: `std::tuple_size` works on a tuple not the tuple elements, try `std::tuple_size<decltype(values)>`

Comment: use `sizeof...(T)` instead

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at the example in the provided reference:

```
template <class T>
void test(T t)
{
    int a[std::tuple_size<T>::value]; // can be used at compile time

    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>::value << '\n'; // or at run time
}

int main()
{
    test(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.14));
}
```

From this example (as well as from the reference itself, see e.g. the second declaration), it could be deduced that the template argument to `std::tuple_size` is the *tuple* type.

As in (in your case)

```
std::cout << std::tuple_size<std::tuple<T...>>::value << '\n';
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          Note: The tuple type is used here
```